# MDX query for parent child hierachy SSAS Multidimension

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am struck up with an issue for parent child hiearchy which it provides the incorrect results.

The fact counts has total sum of 1000 but it is resulting the sum 5000 with descendants.

Below is the query.

```html
SELECT
         {
          [Measures].[Factcount]
} ON 0,
Descendants(
    [Location].[ParentLocation].[ParentLocation]
    1,
    SELF_AND_AFTER) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]`
```

Comment: Are you talking about the total displayed on the UI? Kindly share a screen shot of the issue.

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear..I have verifed in the cube browser with hierarchy filters expression and it gives the correct results but when I have run above query in the ssas MDX analyser.it is not showing the proper results...

Comment: The  parent child dimension has 15 levels of the hierarchy when i ran the query it is showing the result with sum from each level in the output..How to flattened the hierarchy levels and verify the results..